# An easy way to get signing certificate from pkcs12 keystore usong alias

Tags: java, xml, security, xml-signature, xades4j

Can anyone tell me if there is an easy way in xades4j to get a signing certificate from a pkcs12 using his alias ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.SigningCertSelector* interface is missing the entry alias. If you really need it now, you can change the *KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.SigningCertSelector* interface and the code on [KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider](http://code.google.com/p/xades4j/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/xades4j/providers/impl/KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.java#187). Probably the *SigningCertSelector* should receive a list of "pairs" {alias, certificate}.